# Diferenças entre getClass().getResourceAsStream() e getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, stream

Na necessidade de carregar um recurso em meu projeto me deparei com estes dois métodos. Da escolha entre um dos dois surgiram algumas dúvidas sobre as quais gostaria de compartilhar aqui.

- Qual a **motivação** ou em que cenário cada um deve ser usado?
- Existe alguma **vantagem** de um relação ao outro? Se sim, qual seria esta?

Comment: Boa pergunta, +1!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A diferença entre como o valor passado como argumento é interpretado é bem sutil.

Basicamente, você tem dois métodos diferentes: `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` e `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. Estes dois métodos irão localizar o recurso de maneira diferente.

## Class.getResourceAsStream()

Em `Class.getResourceAsStream(caminho)`, o caminho é interpretado como um caminho local para o pacote da classe que você está o método.

Por exemplo, chamando `String.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt")` será procurado um arquivo em seu classpath no seguinte local: `java/lang/file.txt`.

Se o caminho começa com um `/`, então ele será considerado um caminho absoluto e começará a procurar a partir da raiz do classpath.

Então, chamando `String.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt")` o arquivo será procurado no seguinte local: `./myfile.txt`.

## ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(caminho)

Já em `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(caminho)`, a implementação considerará que todos os caminhos sejam absolutos.

Então, chamando `String.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsString("myfile.txt")` e `String.getClassLoader().getResourceAsString("/myfile.txt")`, ambos procurarão pelo mesmo arquivo no **classpath**, no seguinte local: `./myfile.txt`.

> Existe alguma vantagem de um relação ao outro? Se sim, qual seria
> esta?

Bom, depende muito dos seus requisitos, detalhes da sua aplicação, inicialmente, o mais óbvio é que, para carregar arquivos dentro do mesmo pacote da sua classe, você deve utilizar: `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

**Recomendo a leitura do seguinte artigo, é bem interessante:** [Smartly load your properties](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077352/smartly-load-your-properties.html)